# Radio button not checked despite value being set in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am sure I am making a trivial mistake. I have a React component with two radio buttons.

```
var OptionsBox = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        console.log("Inside render");
        console.log(this.props.numberingPositionAtStart);
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="radio">
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="radioNumberingPositionOptions" id="numberingPositionAtStart" value="1" onChange={this._onClick} checked={this.props.numberingPositionAtStart}  />
                Append numbering at the beginning of tweets
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div className="radio">
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="radioNumberingPositionOptions" id="numberingPositionAtEnd" value="0" onChange={this._onClick} checked={!this.props.numberingPositionAtStart} />
                Append numbering at the end of tweets
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    },

    _onClick: function(event){
        if (event.target.value == 1)
            {
                TweetSmartActionCreator.numberingpositionatstart(true);
            }
        else{
            TweetSmartActionCreator.numberingpositionatstart(false);
        }

    }
});
```

The output from the console is

```
Inside render
false
```

However, its always the first radio button that is always checked. Even on change, the first radio button remains checked.

Even during the first render, the value is false, so the second button should be checked but that is not the case. How do I go about debugging this?

Comment: Seems to be working as intended: http://jsfiddle.net/pgxkvw3t/ . I'm on Chrome 46 and Safari 9

Comment: It does work as expected when I use it in a web page as can be seen at http://tweetsmart.in/popup.html , but I am trying to make a chrome extension and using the same code and for some reason it does not seem to work as expected there.

Comment: Then, please, clarify your question and add other related code. This React component works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're passing and `String` as value for `numberingPositionAtStart` prop, like `"false"` instead of the boolean `false`.

Check out these three lines will select the first checkbox:

```
React.render(<OptionsBox name="World" numberingPositionAtStart="true" />, document.body);

React.render(<OptionsBox name="World" numberingPositionAtStart="false" />, document.body);

React.render(<OptionsBox name="World" numberingPositionAtStart={true} />, document.body);
```

While the following line will render the desired result:

```
React.render(<OptionsBox name="World" numberingPositionAtStart={false} />, document.body);
```

You can read details about it in [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/false-in-jsx.html).

Comment: You are correct. Due to storing the value in localStorage, bool was becoming string and then being passed as string!